# What is the target variable in the feed forward neural network within the Transformer model architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, attention

In the paper 'Attention is all you need' the model architecture of The Transformer is described. Both in the encoder as well as in the decoder, there is a feed forward network. If I understant it correctly, the input to this feed forward network is the embedding/ continuous representation with similar dimensions.

However, who can tell me what the target variable is on which the neural network is trained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have or need a target variable, because it is just used as a component of the larger transformer model.

When the transformer model is trained (on say a translation task, where the target variable is the target sentence), all the parameters, including those of the feed-foward network will also be trained.

Comment: when u say trained on the feed forward network, is it only on the decoder linear layer or on all the feed forward layer the tranformer consists? I mean incl. the encoder and decoder feed forward layers?